Used to with different time aspects

I used to do it when she came

I used to be doing it when she came

I used to have done it when she came

I used to have been doing it when she came


They all have sligthly different meanings. As I was told I could only use "used to" in the first sentence because "used to" only goes with a bare infinitve. So how can we express the meaning of 2,3 and 4 with "used to"? Is it even possible?


is fine and implies that you did it as a consequence of her coming, each time she came.

is also fine. It means you would always happen to be doing it whenever she came.


3 and 4 don't work. They are simply wrong to a native speaker. I would replace "used to" with "would" in both cases.

many people told me that 2 is wrong too. Why do you think differently?

@Gregor. All I can say, as a native speaker, is that it is not strictly wrong, as long as you mean it as I have said. It's unusual but possible and would need specific circumstances to make sense, but it's not simply wrong in the way that 3 and 4 are.

It would be far more natural to use would usually in 2, 3 and 4 instead of used to. I don't know why, it's 'just the way we say it'.

@Kate, I agree about "would usually" in 2 but I still think it's not wrong in the same way that 3 and 4 are.

"Used to" is dangerous. In your earlier questions involving "when she came," I've talked about it being a single point in time, the moment she walked through the door. But "used to" is often used to talk about past "general patterns" of frequently recurring behavior ("When I was a kid my dad used to walk me down to the bus stop"). Under the influence of this usage, "when she came" is likely to take on the meaning "whenever she came," generally and frequently. Note, in this and similar questions you've given a single sentence with no context. In real usage, context would either have supported this usage, or perhaps pointed in a different direction which might make "used to" a poor choice. There's even a lack of clarity right now about what "when she came" means: When she arrived? Or when she "came over" i.e. paid a visit, as a broader length of time? Other questions have assumed "arrived," a point in time. This one is more likely to assume "came over," a broad and vague period of time.
With that out of the way:

#1 is fine. "My Korean grandmother would have lunch with us every Sunday. I used to make bulgogi when she came."
I'm going to take the position that none of the other examples are likely in this sentence with "used to." I could imagine them being part of a story in sentences that come right after a "used to" sentence, but not being right in the same sentence. I could imagine all of the following:
"My grandmother used to come over on Sundays. I would be making bulgogi when she arrived." —You'll notice I fell back upon an "arrived" (moment in time) meaning to find an excuse to use the "be doing." It just doesn't get along well with the "used to come over" general-pattern meaning. And you'll notice I had to use "would."
"My grandmother used to come over on Sundays. I always would have made a quick kimchi the night before."
"My grandmother used to come over on Sundays. I always would have been making kimchi for hours before she arrived, but I made sure the kitchen was tidy by the time she got there."

In all these, I have dodged your question "how does 'used to' relate to these verb tenses" by saying "In all but the infinitive, it doesn't." I simply used "used to" to establish a past-tense setting for a story, and then used the other tenses as usual. I hope that isn't "cheating," but I think it's the only idiomatic answer.
